# Update scan accumulator while passing along filtered value

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to use `scan` to maintain an array of data and do some filtering.

```
someObservable$.pipe(
   filter(initial=> initial.length !== 0),
   scan((acc, curr) => curr.filter(x => !acc.includes(x))),
   map(data => etc...)
)
```

I would like to update the acc value so that it somehow maintains a comprehensive list of all the data that has come through, but only outputs the filtered values to map.
So if the first list passed through was
`[1,2,3]` and  the second set was `[2,3,4]` On the first pass I want `data` to be`[1,2,3]` and have `acc=[1,2,3]` and on the second past have `data` be `[4]` but have `acc=[1,2,3,4]`

I'm going about this in an obtuse manner? I feel like there might be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add) class for accumulator in `scan` function

I looked in rxjs documentation for any built-in alternative but couldn't find any suitable for this case.

Please take a look at the example.

```js
var subject = new rxjs.Subject();

const obs = subject.pipe(
  rxjs.operators.scan((acc, current) => {current.map(pr => acc.add(pr)); return acc;}, new Set()) // 1 solution
  //rxjs.operators.scan((acc, current) => [...new Set([...acc, ...current])]) // 2 solution
  //rxjs.operators.scan((acc, current) => [...acc, ...current.filter(pr => !acc.includes(pr))]) // 3 solution - if you cant use Set
  //rxjs.operators.scan((acc, current) => acc.concat(current.filter(pr => !acc.includes(pr)))) // 4 solution - if you cant use Set and spread
);

const subscription = obs.subscribe(val => {
  console.log([...val]);
});

subject.next([1,2,3]);
subject.next([2,3,4]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am guessing your intentions right, the following code should suffice:

```
static acc = new Set<number>();
...
return someObservable$.pipe(
  map( list => {
    let res = [];
    list.forEach( e => {
      if ( !acc.has( e ) ) {
        acc.set( e );
        res.push( e );
      }
    } );
    return res;
  } ),
  filter( list => list.length > 0 )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`scan` delivers all intermediate values of `acc`- so `data` is always `acc` it cannot have another value.